# How to clicking a button start python script and block the button, until it completes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have simple site and need to do script in one button. I am using flask in my project

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="a_demo_five" onclick="alert('test')" id="mybutton">
NAME_BUTTON
</a>
```

Python

```
@app.route('/SomeFunction')
def SomeFunction():
    print('There will be my future script')
    return "Nothing"
```

Comment: What do you mean with "block the button"? It should become disabled until `something` completes?

Comment: yes waiting for the script to finish and prevent users from clicking the button again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you should use a  element, unless you need the anchor.
And just set the `disabled` property with some logic that change the value when  `SomeFuntion()` finishes.

Sorry that I can't show you a python example, but I'll leave the idea of what you could try to get your goal (I'm using Javascript):

```js
function SomeFunction() {
  const myButton =  document.getElementById("mybutton");
  // Start making disable the button
    myButton.disabled = true;
  // After doing something
   setTimeout(function(){ 
      console.log('There will be my future script'); 
  // the function finish re-enabling the button
    myButton.disabled = false;
   }, 3000);      
  
  return "Nothing"
}
```

```html
<button href="#" class="a_demo_five" onclick="SomeFunction()" id="mybutton"
>
NAME_BUTTON
</button>
```

*I put a timer of 3 seconds to make easier to get the idea

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit can't understand how to link this javascript to index.html
I put your code in goPython.js file
and in index.html wrote this:
<script src="{{url_for('static', filename='../static/network_search/js/goPython.js')}}"></script>
and it's still doen't work

Comment: Did you update your html? I mean, did you change <a> tag with <button> just my answer?